# How can the cycles be chosen so that they all have length 2 in case of permutation group?

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

I am reading *linear algebra* book by **Harvey E. Rose** . There in *permutation groups* , he says ,

> every permutation can be expressed as product of cycles

I understood this line. 
. Then he said ,

> A cycle of length n can be written in a number of ways as a product of
>   2-cycles, one of which is given by
>
> $ (1,2,3, ... ,n) = (1,2)(1,3)...(1,n) $
>
> the reader should check this, noting we always read from left to right.

I can't understand the meaning of last two lines.

Comment: I can't understand what you find hard to understand about the quoted lines, which seem crystal clear to me. Do you understand the meaning of the identity $$(1,2,3,\dots n)=(1,2)(1,3)\dots(1,n)?$$ Are you able to verify that identity? Or is that your problem, that you don't see why it's true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X = \{1,...,n\}$, the permutations being discussed are bijective functions from $X$ to $X$, and the multiplication is just composition of functions, in left-to-right evaluation order (i.e., the left-most function gets the actual the input). This is the opposite of the usual right-to-left evaluation order for composition notation, but some authors prefer this.

Thus, the permutation with cycle notation
$$(1,2,3,...,n)$$
is the function $f$ which maps
$$1 \to 2,\;\;2 \to 3,\;...\;,(n-1) \to n,\;\;n \to 1$$
and for $1 \le i < j \le n$, the transposition with cycle notation $(i,j)$ is the function $t_{i,j}$ which maps $i \to j,\;j \to i$, and leaves all other values fixed (unchanged).

Thus, the claim
$$(1,2,3, ... ,n) = (1,2)(1,3)...(1,n)$$
is equivalent to the claim (using standard right-to-left evaluation order)
$$f  = t_{1,n}\,\circ\,t_{1,{n-1}}\,\circ\cdots\circ\,t_{1,2}$$
To verify the claim, apply both sides to an arbitrary input $k$, and compare . . .

Thus, for example, we have $f(1)=2$, and also
\begin{align*}
&(t_{1,n}\,\circ\,t_{1,{n-1}}\,\circ\cdots\circ\,t_{1,2})(1)\\[4pt]
=\;&(t_{1,n}\,\circ\,t_{1,{n-1}}\,\circ\cdots\circ\,t_{1,3})(2)\\[4pt]
=\;&2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
since the transposition $t_{1,2}$ maps $1 \to 2$, but the transpositions $t_{1,n},\;t_{1,{n-1}},...,t_{1,3}$ leave $2$ unchanged.

More generally, for $1 \le k < n$, we have $f(k)=k+1$, and also
\begin{align*}
&(t_{1,n}\,\circ\,t_{1,{n-1}}\,\circ\cdots\circ\,t_{1,2})(k)\\[4pt]
=\;&(t_{1,n}\,\circ\,t_{1,{n-1}}\,\circ\cdots\circ\,t_{1,k})(k)
&&\text{[since$\;t_{1,j}\;$fixes$\;k$, if$\;j < k$]}\\[4pt]
=\;&(t_{1,n}\,\circ\,t_{1,{n-1}}\,\circ\cdots\circ\,t_{1,k+1})(1)
&&\text{[since$\;t_{1,k}\;$maps$\;k \to 1$]}\\[4pt]
=\;&k+1
&&\text{[since$\;t_{1,k+1}\;$maps$\;1 \to k+1$}\\[-1pt]
&&&\;\text{and$\;t_{1,j}\;$fixes$\;k+1$, if$\;j>k+1$]}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Finally, we have $f(n)=1$, and also
\begin{align*}
&(t_{1,n}\,\circ\,t_{1,{n-1}}\,\circ\cdots\circ\,t_{1,2})(n)\\[4pt]
=\;&t_{1,n}(n)
&&\text{[since$\;t_{1,j}\;$fixes$\;n$, if$\;j < n$]}\\[4pt]
=\;&1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Thus, the claimed equality$\;(1,2,3, ... ,n) = (1,2)(1,3)...(1,n)\;$is verified.